# Is the any way to install Vuetify 2 on Vue 3?

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs3, migration, vuetify2

I need to migrate a fairly large app from Vuetify2/Vue2 to Vuetify3/Vue3. It seems easier to me to migrate to Vue3 first, since now you can continue to use the Option API in Vue3.

Comment: No, there isn’t. You’ll have to bite the bullet and do it all at once. Depending on the application might go easily, or take a while.

Comment: Hi @SamiKuhmonen, thanks for your comment. Could you elaborate? What's preventing Vuetify 2 from working on Vue 3?

Comment: for one, Vue 3 plugins must implement an installation function using a different syntax than Vue 2.  This change to the installation can only be done by the library maintainers.

Comment: Vue 3 requires quite different way of registering things and Vuetify 2 also uses some internal things of Vue 2 that aren’t available, not even with compat things. Vuetify is one of the more complex ones. Some controls will work quite directly in Vuetify 3, but some do need work and everything of course needs to be tested. I personally just ditched Vuetify and use a different library due to their lack of progress for years.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen can you give me the name of your new library please? Are you happy with it?

Comment: @khamaileon I assume it’s allowed in the comments. I switched to PrimeVue and have been quite satisfied. Much easier to adjust styling when needed, much less divs in the output, and the couple of lacking features I noticed were added right before I even reported them. And it’s much easier to modify the controls myself if I need to, the code is much simpler. So for me was worth the effort and didn’t need to look at the slow progress of Vuetify. Also, you can probably convert to PrimeVue with Vue 2 and then switch to Vue 3 after

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Thanks for the feedback and very good advice about the migration. This will be the designated answer for me! 